# Video, embed, html block usage out of the_content

Tags: block-editor, embed, videos

I have tried hundreds ways but i couldn't do yet. I am beginner, please someone help me !

When admin use for add/upload/embed video any 3 of these blocks; video, core-embed and html i will show the output without use the_content.

---

```
function swvideo( $html) {

if ( $html ) {
    return $html;
}

$post = get_post( $post );
if ( ! $html ) {
    return $html;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'has_blocks' ) ) {
    return $html;
}

if ( ! has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
    return $html;
}

$pattern = "/<!--\ wp:html.*-->([\s\S]*?)<!--\ \/wp:html -->/i";
preg_match_all( $pattern, $post->post_content, $html );
if ( ! empty( $html[1] ) ) {
    $html = reset( $html[1] );
}

return $html;
```

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'swvideo');

Comment: where is `html` defined? did you mean to check `$content`?

Comment: Isn't HTML Block structure html ? I mean when we use embed block i have used "core-embed/youtube". Than i tought that if i use html block i must use $html. Am i wrong ?

Comment: you are using a filter, and the only thing that this filter function gets given is, in your case, the variable `$content`. the variable `$html` is not known or defined in your filter function. try and change the code to `function swvideo( $html)` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it before many times with many variation but nothing happened.

`function swvideo( $html) {
 if ( $html ) {
  return $html;
 }
 $post = get_post( $post );
 if ( ! $html ) {
  return $html;
 }
 if ( ! function_exists( 'has_blocks' ) ) {
  return $html;
 }
 if ( ! has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
  return $html;
 }
 $pattern = "/<!--\ wp:html.*-->([\s\S]*?)<!--\ \/wp:html -->/i";
 preg_match_all( $pattern, $post->post_content, $html );
 if ( ! empty( $html[1] ) ) {
  $html = reset( $html[1] );
 }
 return $html;
}`
add_filter( 'the_content', 'swvideo');

Comment: And these are in my single.php;

`
 <?php 
if(has_block('core/video') || has_block('core-embed/youtube') || has_block('core/html')) { the_content(); } ?>
`

but nothing happening. All post content seems. I just want video seems here.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments to clarify a problem with your code:

```
function swvideo( $html) {

  if ( $html ) { // if $html == true
    return $html;
  }

  $post = get_post( $post ); // irrelevant
  if ( ! $html ) { // if $html != true
    return $html;
  }
  ...
```

As you can see, nothing past this point will be executed, because the input $html must either be equivalent to true, or not equivalent to true.

I can't tell clearly what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe [advanced custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) would help?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just want that a video will seems in predefined place. So i thought that there are 3 ways; 1-) video embed block 2-) video block 3-) html block. How can we do that out of  the_content ? Or how we can filter the_content and show only video contents in predefined place ?